# Horse racing database; how to do this the right way?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am building a database for horse racing. Each race result has (at least) following parameters:

- Race name
- race date (I thought of making these two the ID for the specific entry)
- Race track
- distance
- underground
- going
- type of race
- discipline of racing
- age of entries

Then we have the horses with the jockeys and trainers and the positions they achieved. Like this:

1. Place:

   - Horse name
   - sire
   - dam
   - owner
   - trainer
   - jockey
   - weight
   - official rating
   - other ratings
   - weight
   - odds
   - draw
   - other stuff.
2. Place (...)
3. and so on.

As there are *a lot* of races in the world, I am struggling to create a structure for the database that links the race and the results and enables to search for the results of a specific horse.

I would be really grateful for a hint how to order the parameters of the race with the results and specific parameters of the horses.

Comment: Horse name, sire, dam are attributes of horse and should be in a separate table. And place needs to know the race the placing is for and other stuff.

Comment: You would likely have a table of races. For instance, the Cheltenham Gold Cup is about 5,294 m, with 22 fences, and some qualifying criteria. It's run every year, but the basic facts about the race don't change (much)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
1 Table for the race places (PlaceId, Name, Address etc)
2 Table for the horses (HorseId, Name, Owner, Age etc)
3 Table for the Jockeys (JockeyId, Name, Company, Age etc)
4 Table for the Races (RaceId, Link to PlaceId, Name, Date etc)
5 Table for the Attendees (Link to RaceId, Link to HorseId, Link to JockeyId, Ranking)
```

Comment: I think races and race dates are too subtly different things; the Grand National is the Grand National regardless of which year it takes place.

Comment: Yes can be. But it could also be the Grand National 2019 and the Grand National 2020.

Comment: But both races are the the same length with the same number of fences (or at least they would have been if it hadn't been cancelled)

Comment: Not sure why my comment was deleted and I get a -1 for it... thanks for the answers, and you are correct... itts not only the small races, much more difficult are the smalll ones that change the name with the sponsor.... but still are targetet by the same trainers every year. So maybe race dates, race distance and kind of race could be the answer?....